# Cancel Action in onPause

Tags: android

In my login Activity, just after the use log in, I sync data and create several tables in sql.
If the user open another app before this process finish, I want to cancel it and delete tables.
I thought I could put it in onPause or onStop, but then, when the process finishes and go to the dashboard activity, onPause or onStop should be called, and I don't want this.

I assume the solution is simple, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say "if the user opens another app", do you mean "if the user leaves my app"? If that's so, you can do the work on a background service instead, without the need of a rollback.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. The thing is I don't have time to reimplement it in a service, right now, I do it in a thread, and my app is about to be released.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind your solution is straightforward - create a flag (say for example shouldRollback) to true when you start your transactions. Once your transaction are successfully completed, you set this flag to false. In your onPause() method, simply check for this flag. If it is true, you know you need to roll back the changes.

I would only suggest this if this is your requirement. Personally, I would process all database operations in a background thread. The thread can run in the background even if other applications are opened. There will be too much overhead (if you have a large number of transactions) to keep rolling back inserts. You could use the transaction methods from the SQLiteDatabase object to automatically roll back changes if they were not completed successfully.

Comment: A background thread would get killed if android decides to kill the App, a safer approach would be to use a service. Other than that, a flag for consistent/inconsistent state should work fine. He can do the rollback when the application starts again.